# How to implement hourly and weekly selected notifications separately in scheduledLocalNotifications array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am new to the `UILocalNotification` concept can any help me how to separate hourly and daily notifications in `scheduledLocalNotifications` array, here hourly notification is default notification and daily notification is user can set which day they need alarm.

Comment: Do you want to separate both notifications on receive? OR while setting it up?

Comment: yes, i want separate both notifications on receive

Answer (score 0):

You can set some unique key to identify your local notification, Check below code for your reference, UserInfo Dictionary below is your Unique key for notification. This should be different for all notification.

**Setting up Local Notification, In Your ViewController.m OR anywhere you want to fire Local Notification**

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
notification.fireDate = notificationDay;
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:strTime forKey:@"time"]; // This is the UNIQUE value to detect notification
notification.userInfo = userInfo;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

On receiving you can fetch that userInfo value.

**Receive Local Notificaiton, In AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

   UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
   for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
   {
       UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
       NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
       NSString *uid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"time"]]; //Here you can detect the notification to cancel particular...
       if ([uid isEqualToString:[[self.arrAlarmList objectAtIndex:sender.tag] valueForKey:@"time"]])
       {
            //Implement code here for this particular notification...
        }
     }
}
```

Hope this will help you out! Thanks.

Comment: here  i need to display user set alarms in tableview and delete same user set alarms in scheduledLocalNotifications

Comment: Then you need to write didReceiveLocalNotification: code in your TableView's delete button method